# SpriteKit- Presenting an SKScene in a new SpriteKit Project

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I just created a new SpriteKit project, and right out of the door **bam!** problem. I ran the project without touching anything, and as it should be, the default hello world project appeared. All good on that front. Now, I created a new Coco Touch Class and named it `test` with the superclass of `SKScene`. Then, in the GameViewController, I changed ***ONLY*** the following line

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
```

to

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "test") {
```

and the game crashed on load.

Am I messing up somewhere when I create the new scene, did I miss something? Any suggestions would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because that line of code of code runs an initializer that unarchives a file from a .sks file, which you didn't create yet for the scene. You probably have a `GameScene` .sks configured but not a test.sks.

You need to create a .sks file if you want to initialize your first scene like that. Otherwise, just create a scene without unarchiving .sks using SKScene initializer `initWithSize:`

Comment: What do I need to do to configure the new test.sks file?

Comment: well, all you have to do is go to file > new > file. then find SpriteKit Scene. name it test.sks and its done for you

Comment: Oh, well that was easy... Thank you for your help Max.